# Как воспроизвести стереозвук Unity (AudioSource)?

Tags: unity3d, аудио

У меня есть `byte[]` стереозвука, чтобы воспроизвести его в Unity, я использую `AudioSource`.

Предисловие - для воспроизведения звука мне нужно создать `AudioSource` и установить для него `AudioClip`.

Как я создаю `AudioClip`

```
...
                audioClip = AudioClip.Create("AudioVoice",
                    (int)decodedBytesNumber,
                    (int)mAudioChannels,
                    (int)(mAudioSampleRate),
                    false);

                audioPlayer.clip = audioClip;
...
```

Затем мне нужно установить данные для аудиоклипа

```
...
            int nSamples = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < samplesNumber; i++)
            {
                byte[] data = null;
                if (audioReader.GetAudioByteData(i, ref data) && data != null)
                {
                    float[] pcmData = AudioReader.Convert16BitByteArrayToAudioClipData(data, (int)mAudioChannels);

                    if (pcmData != null && pcmData.Length > 0)
                    {
                        audioPlayer.clip.SetData(pcmData, nSamples);
                        nSamples += pcmData.Length;
                    }
                }
            }
...
```

и есть метод, который я использую для преобразования `byte[] -> float[]`

```
    public static float[] Convert16BitByteArrayToAudioClipData(byte[] source, int channelNumber = 1)
    {
        float[] result = null;

        if (channelNumber == 0)
        {
            channelNumber = 1;
        }

        const int Int16InBytes = sizeof(Int16);

        short maxValue = short.MaxValue;

        float[][] channels = new float[channelNumber][];
        for (int i = 0; i < channelNumber; i++)
            channels[i] = new float[source.Length / Int16InBytes / channelNumber];

        for (int wordNo = 0; wordNo < source.Length / Int16InBytes; wordNo++)
        {
            var channelNo = wordNo % channelNumber;
            var indexInChannel = wordNo / channelNumber;
            var channel = channels[channelNo];
            float value = (float)BitConverter.ToInt16(source, wordNo * Int16InBytes) / maxValue;
            channel[indexInChannel] = value;
        }

        if(channelNumber == 1 /*mono*/)
        {
            result = channels[0];
        }
        else if(channelNumber == 2 /*stereo*/)
        {
            result = new float[channels[0].Length + channels[1].Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < channels[0].Length; ++i)
            {
                result[i * 2] = channels[0][i];
                result[i * 2 + 1] = channels[1][i];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

**Проблема** - если я использую моно звук, он воспроизводит без проблем `AudioReader.Convert16BitByteArrayToAudioClipData(data, 1 <--- mono)`, но если стерео `AudioReader.Convert16BitByteArrayToAudioClipData(data, 2 <- - стерео) то слышно прерывистый звук.

Также я обнаружил, что с байтами проблем нет, потому что я попытался записать их все в файл `.wav`, и он без проблем воспроизводиться.

Костыль который придумал - изменить этот метод `Convert16BitByteArrayToAudioClipData`

```
...
        else if(channelNumber == 2 /*stereo*/)
        {
            result = channels[0];   <----- ТУТ

            //result = new float[channels[0].Length + channels[1].Length];

            //for (int i = 0; i < channels[0].Length; ++i)
            //{
            //    result[i * 2] = channels[0][i];
            //    result[i * 2 + 1] = channels[1][i];
            //}
        }
...
```

и так же установить, что мы хотим использовать один канал

```
...
                audioClip = AudioClip.Create("AudioVoice",
                    (int)decodedBytesNumber,
                    1  /*chanel num*/,             <--------------- ТУТ
                    (int)(mAudioSampleRate),
                    false)
...
```

Костыль работает так, что я получаю стереозвук, затем делю его на два канала и проигрываю только один из них, в результате получается монофонический звук, но по крайней мере это работает без проблем и прирываний.

**В итоге вопрос** - в чем здесь проблема? Почему это работает, когда я пытаюсь воспроизвести моно звук, а не работает когда стерео?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге проблема оказалась в том, что нужно при работе с юнити `AudioClip` нужно продвигать offset на количество самплов деленое на количество каналов. Пример внизу взятый из вопроса и исправлен

```
...
            int nSamples = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < samplesNumber; i++)
            {
                byte[] data = null;
                if (audioReader.GetAudioByteData(i, ref data) && data != null)
                {
                    float[] pcmData = AudioReader.Convert16BitByteArrayToAudioClipData(data, (int)mAudioChannels);

                    if (pcmData != null && pcmData.Length > 0)
                    {
                        audioPlayer.clip.SetData(pcmData, nSamples);
                        nSamples += (pcmData.Length / mAudioChannels);  <--------- This line
                    }
                }
            }
...
```